# Try to match conditional column in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to mongodb and now using aggregate.
I am in a problem that I have 2 column let this column1 and column2 I want to match either by column1 or column2 inside $match Is it possible. I am getting stuck please help.

db Structure:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("55794aa1be1f8fe822da139d"),
  "transactionType" : "1",
   "_store" : {
    "storeLocation" : "Pitampura",
    "storeName" : "Godown",
    "_id" : "5576b5c5e414d90c03d1e330"
  }
}
```

I am try to filter according to transactionType and storeName, I am sending these 2 params to api but when storeName sended as empty string then only filter according to transactionType else by both paramater. Not wanted to use if-elseif.

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: Sounds like a basic [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operation. Unless this is an aggregation condition outside `$match` which means [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/or/) instead.

Comment: No $or cant not satisfy my condition when storeName=" " this try to match with that column

Comment: @ErAjitKumar First timer. See how my comment is prefixed with your username and the `@` character. This is how you "tag" and alert someone who has left a comment for you for clarification. Generally we expect edits to your question to explain the questions and then a comment tagging that person to alert them you have done something about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well of course it can suit your query. You just handle as follows:

```js
// Initial data
var request = { "storeName": "", "transactionType": "1" };

// Transform to array
var conditions = Object.keys(request).map(function(key) {
    var obj = {},
        newKey = "";
    if ( key == "storeName" ) {
        newKey = "_store." + key;
    } else {
        newKey = key;
    }

    obj[newKey] = request[key];
    return obj;
});

db.collection.find({ "$or": conditions });
```

Where the whole structure after transformation breaks down to :

```js
db.collection.find({
    "$or": [
        { "_store.storeName": "" },
        { "transactionType": "1" }
    ]
})
```

Which of course matches the document on the condition that "transactionType" is met.

So that is what [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) does, considers that at least one of the conditions in the query arguments matches data in the document.

The other thing here is that since the data presented in the request is not a "direct match" for the data in the document, manipulation is done on the "key name" to use the correct ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) form for acessing that element.

These are just basic queries, so the same rules apply to aggregation [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/), which is just a query element itself:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Possibly other pipeline before

    // Your match phase, which probably should be first
    { "$match": {
        "$or": [
            { "_store.storeName": "" },
            { "transactionType": "1" }
        ]
    }},

    // Other aggregagtion pipeline

])
```